# Any boolean function could be expressed via equivalence, addition modulo 2 and majority function

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Prove that any boolean function (of any number of arguments) could be written using this three functions:

$1. x \leftrightarrow y$ $-$ equivalence ,

$2. x \oplus y$ $-$ addition modulo 2 (exclusive or)

$3.maj(x,y,z)$ - majority function, which returns the most common number between $x,y,z$

Comment: Do you already know some other functionally complete sets of Boolean operators? Pick such a set, and show that each of its members can be realized using the three tools you have available here.

Comment: OK, according to the Wikipedia i need to realize all from $\{\wedge,\lor,\neg,\rightarrow,\leftrightarrow\}$ using $\{\leftrightarrow, \oplus, maj\}$. But actually it is enough to realize only $\neg$ and one of $\{\wedge,\lor,\rightarrow\}$. So $\neg A:= maj(A \leftrightarrow A, A \oplus (A \leftrightarrow A), A \oplus (A \leftrightarrow A))$ and $A\lor B:=maj(A \oplus (\neg A),A,B)$. And all is done, am i right?

Comment: You can also get $\neg A$ as $(A\leftrightarrow A)\oplus A$.

Comment: Yes, and also i can simplify $A\lor B:=maj(A \leftrightarrow A,A,B)$.

Comment: @qHedg Of course, this argument only goes through *if* you've already established that $\{\neg,\lor\}$ is a functionally complete set. Last I checked, "Because Wikipedia said so" is not a valid proof step nor likely to be accepted by someone marking the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider $\{\wedge,\lor,\neg,\rightarrow,\leftrightarrow\}$ a basic "functionally complete set" (i.e. set of boolean operators, combinations of which give us any possible boolean function) and hence our goal is to realize all from $\{\wedge,\lor,\neg,\rightarrow,\leftrightarrow\}$ using $\{\leftrightarrow, \oplus, maj\}$.

But it is enough to realize only $\neg$ and one of $\{\wedge,\lor,\rightarrow\}$, because

$A \to B := \neg A \lor B$,

$A \leftrightarrow B := (A \to B) \land (B \to A)$,

$A \lor B := \neg(\neg A \land \neg B)$,

$A \vee B := \neg A \rightarrow B$.

So we check (via truth table) that

$\neg A:= maj((A \leftrightarrow A) \oplus A))$,

$A\lor B:=maj(A \leftrightarrow A,A,B)$.

And we are done.